# Path to a folder that is outside the current folder

Tags: php, path, directory

I have a file index.php in   **jobLister/jobs/pakistan/chemical/index.php**   and I want to include a file inside the index.php whose location is jobLister/config/init.php.

I have tried using ../config/init.php but that does not work.

Error that I get:
 No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\jobLister\jobs\pakistan\Chemical\index.php

Comment: show us a full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
../../../config/init.php
```

or the full absolute path.

What you are using is trying to retrieve the file from

`obLister/jobs/pakistan/config` , hence the error